# Expression that captures all characters up to a group of characters

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have several alerts coming from a DC server, which have the following pattern:

```
alert - name risk score - severity - total
```

The examples of these alerts would be:

```
A member was added to a security-enabled local group 47 medium 2
A member was added to a security-enabled universal group 47 medium 1
A security-enabled global group was changed 73 high 2
A security-enabled local group was changed 73 high 2
A user account was locked out  47 medium 31
An attempt was made to reset an accounts password  73 high 14
Member added to security-enabled global group  73 high 2
PowerShell Keylogging Script 73 high 23
PowerShell Suspicious Script with Audio Capture Capabilities 47 medium 23
More Than 3 Failed Login Attempts Within 1 Hour  47 medium 6
Over 100 Connection from 10 Diff. IPs 47 medium 234
Over 100 Connections Attempted 73 high 123
Failed Logins Not Followed by Success Within 2 Hours 21 low 8
```

I've been using the following pattern to capture only the name of the alerts:

```
^(\D*)
```

Essentially, this filters out all of the digits, but now have I received a few alerts I hadn't accounted for. These alerts contain digits in them. For example:

```
More Than 3 Failed Login Attempts Within 1 Hour  47 medium 6
Over 100 Connection from 10 Diff. IPs 47 medium 234
Over 100 Connections Attempted 73 high 123
Failed Logins Not Followed by Success Within 2 Hours 21 low 8
```

So I need to be able to capture the complete name, otherwise, I'm ending up with:

```
More than
Over
Over
Failed Logins Not Followed by Success Within
```

Despite my efforts, I have not been able to capture the desire pattern. This would be the desired output:

```
A member was added to a security-enabled local group
A member was added to a security-enabled universal group
A security-enabled global group was changed
A security-enabled local group was changed
A user account was locked out 
An attempt was made to reset an accounts password 
PowerShell Keylogging Script 
PowerShell Suspicious Script with Audio Capture Capabilities
More Than 3 Failed Login Attempts Within 1 Hour
Over 100 Connection from 10 Diff. IPs 
Over 100 Connections Attempted
Failed Logins Not Followed by Success Within 2 Hours
```

Thanks for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative possible re. **Note:** I am anticipating that `alerts` is a list of strings.
The pattern matches any string of characters at the beginning of the string `^(.*)`, followed by `\s` which matches any whitespace character. `(\d+)` matches one or more digits   then one or more letters `(\w+)` and one or more digits `(\d+)` at the end of the string `($)`.

```py
import re

data = """
A member was added to a security-enabled local group 47 medium 2
A member was added to a security-enabled universal group 47 medium 1
A security-enabled global group was changed 73 high 2
A security-enabled local group was changed 73 high 2
A user account was locked out  47 medium 31
An attempt was made to reset an accounts password  73 high 14
Member added to security-enabled global group  73 high 2
PowerShell Keylogging Script 73 high 23
PowerShell Suspicious Script with Audio Capture Capabilities 47 medium 23
More Than 3 Failed Login Attempts Within 1 Hour  47 medium 6
Over 100 Connection from 10 Diff. IPs 47 medium 234
Over 100 Connections Attempted 73 high 123
Failed Logins Not Followed by Success Within 2 Hours 21 low 8
"""

alerts = data.splitlines()

pattern = re.compile(r'^(.*)\s\d+\s\w+\s\d+$')

for alert in alerts:
    res = pattern.search(alert)
    if res:
        print(res.group(1))
```

You can also choose to use a [`list-comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to store all the matches and then unpack the entire list instead of using the above for-loop to print one match at a time:

```py
res = [pattern.search(alert).group(1) 
        for alert in alerts if pattern.search(alert)]
print(*res, sep="\n")
```

---

```
A member was added to a security-enabled local group
A member was added to a security-enabled universal group
A security-enabled global group was changed
A security-enabled local group was changed
A user account was locked out
An attempt was made to reset an accounts password
Member added to security-enabled global group
PowerShell Keylogging Script
PowerShell Suspicious Script with Audio Capture Capabilities
More Than 3 Failed Login Attempts Within 1 Hour
Over 100 Connection from 10 Diff. IPs
Over 100 Connections Attempted
Failed Logins Not Followed by Success Within 2 Hours
```

Comment: Hey, that worked well. Thank you for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 2):

The following regex should do the trick: `.*\b(?= \d* .* \d*$)`

The `(?=...)` syntax is called a lookahead, and it allows us to specify the text that must follow the specified regex. Here, we're essentially looking for anything followed by the pattern: space, number, space, anything, space, number, end of line.

Comment: Hey Seon, I tried your suggestion, but it didn't quite work. I'm not sure why. I voted your answer up but went with @JamiuS.' answer, which worked for me. Thank you for taking the time to help!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @CUI. Do you have an example where it fails so I can fix the answer for future users?

Comment: Sure thing. I'm trying to edit my orginal post so that I can add the actual code, but I keep getting a message saying there are too many pending edits lined up on SO. I'll try again later.